# Property X is not a member of T

Tags: swift, swift5

I have this:

```
struct ViewA: View {
  @ObservedObject var model:MyModelA
  var button:MyModelA.LocalButton

struct LocalButton:Hashable {
  var name:String
  var isCentralButton:Bool = false
}
  // bla bla bla
}
```

and

```
struct ViewB: View {
  @ObservedObject var model:MyModelB
  var button:MyModelB.LocalButton

  struct LocalButton:Hashable {
    var name:String
    var isCentralButton:Bool = false
  }
  // bla bla bla
}
```

I want to create a generic view that accepts all kinds of models

So I started by doing this

```
protocol BarButtonProtocol: ObservableObject {}
// I have assigned this to MyModelA and MyModelB

struct MyGenericView<T:BarButtonProtocol> : View {
      @ObservedObject var model:T
      var button:T.LocalButton
```

First line is fine but I have an error on the last line...

> LocalButton is not a member of T.

Comment: Of course since T is an ObservableObject and nothing else. You need to create a protocol that both MyModelA and MyModelB conforms to and let T be of that type

Comment: I have created the protocol and assigned that to MyModelA and MyModelB. same error. I appreciate if you can show some code. Thanks.

Comment: I have added more code. Sorry. I have failed to mention that LocalButton is a struct.

Comment: You should move LocalButton outside of any other type if it is the same one in both cases. `var button:MyModelA.LocalButton` makes no sense, it should be just `var button: LocalButton`